# iOS Camera alternatives to make photo segregation/ album filing easier / faster?

Tags: ios, photos

Are there any alternative Camera apps that make it easier to push the just taken (or batch of just taken) photos immediately into a specific album?

More details: I use the camera app a lot for mundane stuff.  Often several pics in a row.  I know I can use the action sheets to select then move the pictures into a specific album, but especially one handed, its a lot of swiping, clicking, and error prone, both in selecting the photos and in picking out the album.

The dream would be to be able to take 1 - 20 pictures, and as soon as they are taken, be able to click a defined shortcut button “move to junk album’ or ‘move to ebay album” and have it move all the pics taken in that photo session, from within the camera app.

Comment: Take a look at [Camera+ 2](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/camera-2/id1313580627). It is very powerful as a camera app, and has advanced filing features. _Note: No financial or other ties to the app developer LateNiteSoft S.L._